# IntelliJ IDEA project modules are not auto identified on WSL

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

The files within my **Gradle** project are not identified by IntelliJ when a project in **WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux)** is opened by **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate**. Correct java versions are also installed within WSL and the paths are also set correctly.

This is a **Gradle** project and my java files are shown with a red icon on them and it says **"Java file outside of source root"**.

Then I went to `File -> Project Structure -> Modules`, and observed that the correct modules were not identified.

When I open the same project in Windows or Ubuntu, the modules are automatically detected and I don't need to add them manually.

How I opened the project is using `File -> Open` on IntelliJ for Windows and gave the project path within WSL (E.g. \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\username\idea-project).

My Gradle versions is as below,

[image]

Has anyone come across any situation like this that could help me figure out what is the issue behind this.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like the project has not been imported as Gradle project successfully. Does this project has Gradle configured? E.g. does it use a Gradle wrapper? Make sure you can run Gradle build on a WSL for this project successfully: run `./gradlew build` from command line in the project root directory for this. If this completes: try reopening the project File | New | Project from Existing Sources action and select the build.gradle file to import from.

Comment: @Andrey `./gradlew build` says BUILD SUCCESSFUL but the external dependencies are also not downloaded. and then I restarted IDE and opened the project with build.gradle file but still no luck.